# Localstorage event does not work in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, web-applications, uiwebview, local-storage

I want to use the localstorage to share data between two uiwebview. so that they could communicate with each other by javascript.

It works in two tabs of chrome(pc) and safari(iphone), but does not work in two uiwebviews.

Here is a simple demo:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
window.addEventListener("storage",function(e){
    if(e.key=="txt"){
        txt.value = e.newValue;
    }
},false);

txt.addEventListener("input",function(){
    localStorage["txt"]=txt.value;
},false);
```

And Obj-c:

```
webview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240)];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.22.182.29:8000/onstoragetest.html"]]];

UIWebView *webview2 = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, 320, 240)];
[self.view addSubview:webview2];
[webview2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.22.182.29:8000/onstoragetest.html"]]];
```

The problem is that the storage event is never fired.

Comment: ever find a solution? thanks